# Entity manager injection in spring + jpa

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I am injecting entityManager in generic DAO using @PersistenceContext. Spring specification says that entity manager injected using @persistenceContext is thread safe.
My generic dao class is as follows.

```
@Repository
public class GenericDAOImpl implements GenericDAO {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager

    // all database methods.
}
```

As you see entityManager is class level variable and there will be only one instance of GenericDAOImpl as it is singleton, entitymanager will be shared with all the requests. As it is thread safe, meaning only one thread can access at a time. So My application can not support multiple database requests. Dont you think this is big drawback from performance point of view? I hope I am doing everything correct according spring spec.

Comment: Being thread safe doesn't mean that only one thread can access it at a time. That's your incorrect definition of "thread-safe". Of course multiple threads can access the entity manager, and thus the database, concurrently.

Comment: @JB Nizet I am confused here. As entity manager will hold persistent entities, if it shared with multiple threads and as there is only one entityManager, entity manager will be mixed up with two thread requests.

Comment: No. The state of the entity manager is bound to the thread, not to the entity manager instance. Let's say thread A uses `em.find(Foo.class, 1)`. The entity manager will look for Foo#1 in a persistence context associated to thread A. If another thread B concurrently calls `em.find(Foo.class, 1)`, the entity manager will look for Foo#1 in a persistence context associated with thread B, and will thus get a difference instance of Foo.

Comment: @JB Nizet As you see, there will be only one instance of GenericDAOImpl, so will be one instance of entityManager. So as per my understanding, it have to share SAME entityManager among threads. Then how different foo instances will be obtained? I am sorry, but still not able to understand the concept.

Comment: I explained it in the previous comment. The unique EM instance uses a ThreadLocal to get the persistence context associated to the current thread.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for your explanation. Is there any way I can test it?